# Are there any gotchas to deleting tags in an upstream repository?

Tags: git, version-control

I know you definitely should not rebase commits that you've already pushed to a remote, as amending history after it has been pushed can cause messes for other developers.

Is it OK though to move a tag in your local repository (`git tag -a -f <tagname>`), delete the remote tag (`git push origin :refs/tags/<tagname`), then push the new tag (`git push --tags`)?

What about non-annotated (lightweight) tags? What about branches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's fine. As long as you tell others that you did that. I like to leave some alternate tag in their place (same for branches) with "-this-moved" at the end of it. After a month or whatever your activity level is, I delete those too.

Comment: Do you have to tell them because they have to do something? Or do you mean just to alleviate the confusion of "where'd my tag go?"

Comment: both.. plus just in case that was something they were using, they can find where it used to be and let you know what you are doing to their work. This is really problematic when doing this in a repo that's a submodule of other repos. I would not recommend.